# Capistrano's run_locally doesn't print to console?

Tags: ruby, deployment, capistrano

Assume I have a custom task in my recipe as such:

```
task :custom_task1 do    
  run_locally "cap -S config=blah another_custom_task
end
```

and

```
task :another_custom_task do
  puts "hi"
end
```

Then, "hi" won't be printed. 
How to fix or overcome the situation? It is not allowing me to use command line whatsoever.

Edit:

Why can't I use logger? 
Capistrano, by default talks too much - so I have a setting that sets its logger to shout only important errors. So can't use logger.info or something as such.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`Logger`](http://rdoc.info/github/capistrano/capistrano/master/Capistrano/Logger):

```
logger.info "hi"
```

Comment: Capistrano is too chatty. So I have disabled its output. `logger.info` wouldn't work.